# Парсинг конфигурационного файла с помощью boost

Tags: config, парсер, boost, c++

Всем привет!

Я новичок в C++ и ещё плохо понимаю, когда какие методы вызываются у классов в C++, поэтому возник вопрос:

Есть файл конфигураций, который нужно пропарсить, решил выбрать библиотеку boost. В ней всё делается относительно просто:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
int a;

po::options_description desc("conf_file");
desc.add_options()
("a",       po::value<int>(&a));

po::variables_map vm;
std::ifstream settings_file("conf.ini");
po::store(po::parse_config_file(settings_file, desc), vm);
settings_file.close();
po::notify(vm);
```

Всё хорошо работает, но собственно вопрос: как заставить это работать в случае, если a - std::complex? Если просто изменением 6-й строки на po::value<std::complex<double>>(&a), то в каком виде задавать переменную в самом файле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В подобных случаях можно поступить от противного. Для начала попытаемся сохранить в файл значение и посмотреть, что оно там запишет. Скорее всего формат будет понятным. И скорее всего там будет что то в виде скобочка, число, запятая, число, скобочка - `(2,3)` или `(3.14, 2.78)`.

Итого, для начала напишите код, который сохранит значение, а потом посмотрите в результирующий файл. После этого можно экспериментировать.

P.S. Скорее всего буст использует операторы `<<` и `>>`. Поэтому можно сделать как я

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   std::complex<double> a(1,2);
   std::cout << a << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

чтение также работает, проверьте.

Comment: Да, спасибо за совет. Сделаю только одну заметку:
Пришлось отказаться от использования program_options в пользу property_tree. Первый, как я вычитал в интернетах, нужен больше для парсинга командной строки и, к тому же, не умеет записывать в файл. В случае property_tree всё оказалось просто: в файл значение выводится так же, как и <<, соответственно, с его чтением не возникло никаких проблем.